# CollectionView grid with images. Images don't fit in the grid

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm trying to create a Grid layout that shows some pictures. Now I'm using a FlowLayout and I create my CollectionView like this:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];


    Gop *g = _images[(NSUInteger) indexPath.row];

    @weakify(self);
    [[self.imageService fetchImageFromURLAsString:g.imageUrl] subscribeNext:^(UIImage *img) {
        @strongify(self);
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];
        imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView];
    } error:^(NSError *error) {
        [_snackbar displaySnackbarWithMsg:NSLocalizedString(@"snackbar.error.no.network", nil)];
    } completed:^{
        DDLogDebug(@"Fetched image");
    }];

    return cell;
}

#pragma mark – UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return CGSizeMake(100,100);
}
```

Don't worry for the reactive cocoa part, it just retrieves an image from the internet.

Now the image is 1920 x 1080 but I want a gallery of images of 100 x 100 for example. So I implemented the UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout method and created a size off 100x100. Now my image don't show 100 x 100 and my image content isn't visible. I only see some image from the left corner I guess ( of the bigger picture ).

How can I fit my images that they are 100 x 100 and all in line with each other?

Screenshot what I have now:

[image]
I hoped on a result something like this:
http://www.appcoda.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/RecipePhoto-App-First-Version.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things:

You should not be displaying `1920x1080` images in the `UICollectionView`, as this will result in **really** bad performance. Doesn't your web service provide previews?

`- (CGSize)collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:` only affects the size of the `UICollectionViewCell`, it does not resize the images. As you have not provided frame of the `UIImageView`, it will take the size of its `UIImage`, which in your case is `1920x1080`. Easy fix would be:

```
//@weakify(self); not necessary, as you are not referencing self inside the blocks
[[self.imageService fetchImageFromURLAsString:g.imageUrl] subscribeNext:^(UIImage *img) {
    //@strongify(self);
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];
    imageView.frame = cell.bounds; // set the frame of the UIImageView
    imageView.clipsToBounds = YES; // do not display the image outside of view, if it has different aspect ratio
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView];
} error:^(NSError *error) {
    [_snackbar displaySnackbarWithMsg:NSLocalizedString(@"snackbar.error.no.network", nil)];
} completed:^{
    DDLogDebug(@"Fetched image");
}];
```

Also, think about the cell reuse: if the cell is reused, all of that code will run multiple times, which will result in multiple `UIImageViews` in the same cell. You can solve this by adding `UIImageView` to the `UICollectionViewCell` in the Interface Builder and only accessing it in the code (e.g. via `tag`):

```
...
UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView*)[cell viewWithTag:YOUR_TAG];
...
```

Also, cell can be potentially reused before the image was loaded from the web service, which will result in multiple images being asynchronously loaded into the same cell, which is quite a mess.

I would suggest to take a look at libraries like `AFNetworking` or `SDWebImage` which have already solved this non-trivial problem.

Comment: Thanks for the frame = cell.bounds. that solved the problem. Now I'm using AFNetworking to fetch the image. What I don't get is the tag example. Why do I need to make a custom cell?

Comment: `AFNetworking` provides `UIImageView` methods for asynchronous loading of images, e.g. `-setImageWithURL:placeholderImage:`. You may be over-complicating things here with `ReactiveCocoa`.

Comment: Will take a look. Then the problem is also solved of the reuse of the cells?

Comment: It doesn't solve the first reuse issue i pointed out: `-dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:` may return the cell, which already has `UIImageView` added from its previous use. One way to solve this is remove old `UIImageView` before adding the new one, but having one created in the interface builder and only referencing it in the code is much simpler.

Comment: Jakub, I now have a custom collectionViewCell with a xib. In the xib there is a ImageView. I set a tag on it and then retrieve the imageview by tag and set the new images. Still got the same problem that you see the previous image when it is recycling..

Comment: Are you using `AFNetworking`s `-setImageWithURL:placeholderImage:`? If you don't specify placeholder image, than previous one will be displayed until new one is loaded.

Comment: If you are still struggling, I would suggest to open new question with updated code

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your cell configuration code:

```
imageView.clipsToBounds = YES
```

Comment: Doesn't change anything.

Comment: Did you set the Delegate of your collection view? Try using `cell.clipsToBounds = YES` before loading image and make sure it's running in the main thread.

Comment: Thanks that solved the problem of the images being separated. Now why is the aspectFill not working? Any idea?

Comment: As your example, they're using scale to fits. You can see example of AspectFill, AspectFit, ScaleToFill, ScaleToFit in [here](http://img.my.csdn.net/uploads/201211/27/1354011953_1051.png). Also, you should set UIView properties out of block, or make sure they are running on the main thread by `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{  // Your code here })`

Comment: I thought that the reactivecocoa block was running on the main queue.